# Prevent page reload when setting session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp button, and on the click event a session variable is set and the page is redirected. The problem is that this process requires two clicks - once to set the session and another to redirect. How can I set the session and redirect in one click? My code is as follows:

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("AnotherPage.aspx");
       Session.Add("user-id", _id);
}
```

Comment: Add session first and then redirect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
    Session.Add("user-id", _id);
    Response.Redirect("AnotherPage.aspx");
}
```